# Flutter Pagination not working after few pages

Tags: flutter, pagination

I am trying to implement pagination function in flutter with Laravel as backend. Issue i am facing is after page 5, flutter is not sending request to server. Is there any reason why this should fail as it works fine till page 5. Or Is there any other solution. There are total of around 90 pages, but it stops after few pages.

plugin used : https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_paginator
api: https://apptest.factory2homes.com/api/products?page=$page

```
body: Paginator.gridView(
        key: paginatorGlobalKey,
        pageLoadFuture: sendPagesDataRequest,
        pageItemsGetter: listItemsGetterPages,
        listItemBuilder: listItemBuilder,
        loadingWidgetBuilder: loadingWidgetMaker,
        errorWidgetBuilder: errorWidgetMaker,
        emptyListWidgetBuilder: emptyListWidgetMaker,
        totalItemsGetter: totalPagesGetter,
        pageErrorChecker: pageErrorChecker,
        scrollPhysics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
          crossAxisCount: 3,
          childAspectRatio: 0.7,),
      ),

    );
  }



  Future<PagesData> sendPagesDataRequest(int page) async {
    print('page ${page}');
    try {

      String url = Uri.encodeFull("https://apptest.factory2homes.com/api/products?page=$page");
      http.Response response = await http.get(url);
      print('body ${response.body}');

      PagesData pagesData = pagesDataFromJson(response.body);
      return pagesData;
    } catch (e) {
      if (e is IOException) {
        /*return CountriesData.withError(
            'Please check your internet connection.');*/
      } else {
        print(e.toString());
        /*return CountriesData.withError('Something went wrong.');*/
      }
    }
  }



  List<dynamic> listItemsGetterPages(PagesData pagesData) {
    List<Datum> list = [];
    pagesData.data.forEach((value) {
      list.add(value);
    });
    return list;
  }

  Widget listItemBuilder(dynamic item, int index) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: (){},
      child: Card(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
                height: 125,
                width: double.maxFinite,
                child: Image.network(
                  item.productPhoto,
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                )),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget loadingWidgetMaker() {
    return Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      height: 160.0,
      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
    );
  }

  Widget errorWidgetMaker(PagesData countriesData, retryListener) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: Text("error"),
        ),
        FlatButton(
          onPressed: retryListener,
          child: Text('Retry'),
        )
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget emptyListWidgetMaker(PagesData countriesData) {
    return Center(
      child: Text('No Products in the list'),
    );
  }

  int totalPagesGetter(PagesData pagesData) {
    return pagesData.lastPage;
  }

  bool pageErrorChecker(PagesData pagesData) {
    //return countriesData.statusCode != 200;
    return false;
  }
```